# How do you estimate the gas cost of any arbitrary function in Remix IDE?

Tags: remix, gas-estimate

I've found plenty of information on how to do this using Truffle and Web3, but nothing regarding how to achieve this in the Remix IDE.


Examples would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put the cursor on the name of the function in Remix, on the top right of the screen you will see the required gas.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: That helps a bit, I never noticed that before. But what about for functions where the execution cost is infinite? Is there a way to input arguments into a certain function to see the gas estimate?

Comment: In most cases, this means that this cannot be estimated. Most of the time is because the function involves dynamic arrays in general, bytes or string who's length the compiler doesn't know in advance. Also if you are calling other contracts the compiler will show infinite gas.

You could just call the function and check the consumed gas. In particular, you can use the java script VM environment in the run tab which runs locally and can tell you the gas.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same functionality in the console window? Just curious, that also might be helpful.

Comment: You mean in geth?, maybe you should create a new question and give more details.

Answer (score 1):

After you have compiled & deployed your code, call your desired function (as shown in following example image which is calling `functionB`) [image: illustration on how to call your desired function], then on right, in console you can see it under `execution cost` (as shown in following image). [image] Remember, it says *"(Cost only applies when called by a contract)"*.