# Find exact gas limit requirements for executing fallback function logic

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-estimate

I have a certain function logic coded for fallback function. This logic also contains some delete operations of storage variables (delete storeVarX;) due to which there might be some gas being refunded. Now the problem this is creating is, when i check the gas used by the fallback function in ethscan, it shows as 29,349. But allocating 30,000 gas or even 50,000 gas units to execute this function raises an [Out of gas] exception.

is there a way I can estimate gas consumed by fallback function, excluding the gas refund due to delete operations?

Comment: How do you invoke the fallback function? If you invoke the function through  `a.transfer()` or a `a.send()` the fallback function has only 2300 gas at disposal..

Comment: The contract expects an EOA (externally owned account) to send ethers to the contract directly and a specific gas units as gas limit. I need to calculate how much gas units are required (minimum gas limit) to successfully execute the fallback function.

Comment: Did you already tried with REMIX IDE as suggested here? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50863/how-do-you-estimate-the-gas-cost-of-any-arbitrary-function-in-remix-ide

Comment: the gas estimate is showing as infinite in remix IDE. I was hoping to try something like gasEstimate() function in web3.